# Convert os.Stdin to []byte

Tags: go, encryption, input, type-conversion, chat

I'm trying to implement a small chat-server in golang with end-to-end encryption. Starting of the example for server https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/tree/master/ch8/chat and client https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/netcat3/netcat.go I stumbled upon https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/02/encrypt-decrypt-data-golang-application-crypto-packages/ to encrypt and decrypt in Go.

The function to encrypt:

```
func encrypt(data []byte, passphrase string) []byte {
block, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(createHash(passphrase)))
gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
ciphertext := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, data, nil)
return ciphertext
}
```

in func main():

```
   ciphertext := encrypt([]byte(os.Stdin), "password")
    mustCopy(conn, ciphertext)
    conn.Close()
```

os.Stdin is os.file, while it is needed as []byte. The solution should be io.Reader or via buffer, but I can't find a working solution.

I tried

```
bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(os.Stdin))
```

and

```
reader := bytes.NewReader(os.Stdin)
```

Any input is more than welcome. Sorry if I'm not seeing the obvious problem/solution here, as I'm fairly new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.Stdin` is an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). You can't convert it to a `[]byte`, but you can *read* from it, and the data you read from it, that may be read into a `[]byte`.

Since in many terminals reading from `os.Stdin` gives data by lines, you should read a complete line from it. Reading from `os.Stdin` might block until a complete line is available.

For that you have many possibilities, one is to use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner).

This is how you can do it:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
if !scanner.Scan() {
    log.Printf("Failed to read: %v", scanner.Err())
    return
}
line := scanner.Bytes() // line is of type []byte, exactly what you need
```

Comment: Also of interest is [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it. My temporary working solution:
`scannerWrite := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)  
  if !scannerWrite.Scan() {  
   log.Printf("Failed to read: %v", scannerWrite.Err())  
   return  
  }  
  line := scannerWrite.Bytes() // line is of type []byte, exactly what you need  
  ciphertext := encrypt([]byte(line), "password")  
  r := bytes.NewReader(ciphertext)  
  mustCopy(conn, r) )`